# discord.py how to connect random choices

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a meme command (where random images come out) personally dedicated to the server and I would like the author of the meme to be mentioned.
But I'm afraid that if I also create images for the author other than the author.
My question is essentially:
How do I put both the image and the author in the same variable? (Sorry if I explained myself wrong)

Code

```
#random image embed
@client.command(aliases=["IM","im"])
async def image_embed(ctx):
    tartufo=[
        'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731555200489357362/salvenee.jpg',
        'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731552604546662511/unknown.png',
        'https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/rocks-balancing-on-driftwood-sea-in-background-picture-id153081592?s=612x612'
    ]
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    )
    embed.set_image(url=random.choice(tartufo))
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Richiesto da {ctx.author.name}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of tuples where the elements of each tuple are the url and author:

```
images = [
    ('url1', 'author1'),
    ('url2', 'author2'),
    ('url3', 'author3'),
    ('url4', 'author4'),
]

url, author = random.choice(images)

embed.set_image(url=url)
embed.set_footer(text=f'Author is {author}')
```